# Actual height not being affected when using visual layer animation?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have two different grids, one stacked up on another. Now I am trying to reduce the size of the first grid(using visual layer animations), such that the other grid now takes up all the space.

```
ScalarKeyFrameAnimation animation1 = compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
        animation1.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, 0);
        animation1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
         visual.StartAnimation(nameof(visual.Scale) + "." + nameof(visual.Scale.Y), animation1);
```

I have tried manipulating both offsets and scale property but none are able to change the actual height of the grid. As a result, the second grid doesn't move from its place.

[image: Live visual tree values]

Above is the live visual tree values, the actual height is not being affected with either scale or offset animation. And no "second grid" taking up entire space animation is happening.

Comment: Next time post the actual code rather than pasting a photo of the code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't aware of such issue!

Answer (score 1):

ActualHeight & ActualWidth are values set by the layout engine.

VisualLayer animations and RenderTransform animations in XAML apply *after* the Layout passes and won't update affect ANY layout properties. They are, for lack of a better word, "Render time" properties. Any changes to them will not affect any layout other object.

If you'd really like this to work, you'd need to use either a [LayoutTransform](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/86808521998a17d05b12756479a60530e17c9459/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/LayoutTransformControl) or animate the Width & Height of the object if they have one set using Storyboards. Noting however, this will cause animations to run on the UI thread because they require the Layout engine to re-run passes every frame, which will reduce performance.

Comment: So there is no way of getting this work using visual layer animation? I was previously using the storyboards animation (enabling dependent animation property) but sometimes there would be glitches in animation and overall it won't be that smooth.

Comment: Nope, there is no way. One of the reasons Visual layer animations perform so well is they do zero layout updates - and re-evaluating visual tree layout is the main reason your storyboard animation wasn't smooth.